# How do you escape characters in heredoc?

Tags: linux, bash, heredoc

I'm working with a bash script trying to stop it from attempting to replace variables inside my heredoc. How do set a heredoc to either A) escape the variable names instead of parsing them or B) return the entire string untouched?

```
cat > /etc/nginx/sites-available/default_php <<END
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/$host; <--- $host is a problem child
}
END
```

As is, when I it finishes injecting it into a file I'm left with this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/;
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the `bash(1)` man page:

> If any characters in *word* are
>          quoted,  the  *delimiter* is the result of quote removal on *word*, and the
>          lines in the here-document are not expanded.

```
cat > /etc/nginx/sites-available/default_php <<"END"
```

Comment: +1 Escaping the "limit string" also works (`\END`). See also http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html#EX71C

Comment: Single quotes work too

Comment: Same mechanism works for Korn shell (ksh).

Comment: It's worth noting that whilst this answers the second option in the OP's question, it doesn't answer the question title. Visitors here might be looking to answer the first option,  where they still need some expansion, in which case they should use the answer by @halfgaar. This answer is still very useful of course, and clearly did serve the OP's purpose.

Comment: @JohnMcCarthy - very helpful to know. Now it makes sense why `'EOF'` works.

Answer (score 37):

Just with a backslash:

```
cat > /tmp/boeboe <<END
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/\$host';
}
END
```

Comment: Do you know how to disable injection of variable values without escaping each one?

Comment: What Ignacio said, but I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 1):

@Xeoncross (and all landing here via search engine results) : it is possible to disable variable substitution by single-quoting the stop token :

```
cat > /tmp/boeboe << 'END'
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/$host;
}

# Example : here is another occurrence of '$host' which won't be substituted either
# When single-quoting the stop token, you don't have to escape all '$myVariable' anymore
END
```